# ImageView showing blank screen on Android device

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I've created an ImageView in my Android application to show a full screen size image in the application. I have appropriate-sized images in drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi folders. When I try to run the app in my phone by installing the generated .apk file, the ImageView shows a blank screen instead of the image. The app, however, works perfectly fine on a number of emulators and even if I run it directly from Eclipse into my phone.
I even tried to view the source folders of drawable-`<screen density>` of the installed app (I have a rooted phone) and the images ARE there in the drawable folders. 
Following is my Android activity XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@+string/bg_img_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_img" />
```

Comment: may be Image is of More resolutions , which your device is not supporting . check the logcat it will show error while loading that image,

Comment: Then why would it show when I'm running the app directly via Eclipse?

Comment: Give some `height` and `width` and check

Comment: @intrepidkarthi Height and width to the image? How?

Comment: once check with  android:scaleType="fitXY" , and what are the resolutions of the Images...

Comment: Nop, `fitXY` didn't work. The resolutons are 640x960, 480x800, and 320x480 for xhdpi, hdpi, and mdpi respectively.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a `jpg` that will display in the Design View in Android Studio, but when I run it on a device or emulator, the image just doesn't display. Logcat  says this: `---- fAsset->read(1024) returned 0` and `--- decoder->decode returned false`. I can load other images, but not this one. Also, when I download the image to my PC, I can open it fine in Firefox or any other Image Viewer.